# Determine the type of a boxed object in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm curious on how to get the type of a boxed object in C#. Here's an example:

```
try{
    ...
}catch(Exception ex){
    //get the specific type of exception
}
```

As you can see, any instance of the subclass of Exception will be caught, now how do you get the specific type?

Please note that above is just an example, I'm not going to use it like that so please don't suggest to catch specific exception.

Here's another example:

Person person = new Person("John");
object obj = person; //box

Now how do you get the type `Person` from `obj`?

Comment: @un-lucky I think it's obvious that I'm pertaining to the object which will be caught. In the catch block, I want to determine the specific type of `ex` since it's boxed.

Comment: While some of the "answers" may apply, they are not answer in full (and I believe it can not be dones...

Assumy you have thousands of declared value types [struct], and one instance of one of them has been boxed into an object, and then passed to Foo(object x).... universally determining that 

a) It is a boxed value type
b) The name of the boxed type

is something I have never found a oslution for in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ways you can do this:

A: Use `GetType()`

```
Type type = ex.GetType()
```

B: Use `is`.

```
if (ex is FileNotFoundException)
{
}
```

(Note that the test above returns true also if `ex` is derived from `FileNoteFoundException`.)

C: If you need additional information about the type, you can use reflection.

```
ex.GetType().GetProperty("PropName"); // Etc.
```

Comment: I prefer the reflection, but how? Thanks

Comment: @dpp: Depends on the information you need. If you just want to get the type, use `GetType()`.

Comment: In my example, am I going to get the `FileNotFoundException` and not `Exception` when I use GetType?

Comment: @dpp: Did you try? I did a test in LINQPad with `Exception ex = new FileNotFoundException(); Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType());`. And the output was *FileNotFoundException*.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a compiler in this machine, can't test it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jonathan's answer, you can also have multiple catch blocks, like so:

```
try
{
}
catch(ExceptionType1 ex)
{
      //Action for ExceptionType1 exception
}
catch(ExceptionType2 ex)
{
      //Action for ExceptionType2 exception
}
...
catch(Exception ex)
{
      //Action for other types of exception
}
```

Just make sure that the order of the exception types are from more specific (child) to less specific (parent).

This answer is only valid for the try ... catch scenario, of course. Otherwise, I prefer the

```
is
```

keyword.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but my actual problem is determining the type of the specific type of the ex, not how to catch different Exceptions, I mentioned that in the post.

Answer (score 1):

How to define what type of variable is:

```
if( err is SomeException)
{
}
```

or (in certain cases if you need to do some more complex type hierarchy stuff that cant be expressed with is)

```
if( err.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SomeException)))
{ }
```

Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

When you convert derived class to base class, then it is called [casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)